# OpenCV: Denoising image / video frame

Tags: c++, opencv, video, noise

I want to denoise a video using OpenCV and C++. I found on the OpenCV doc site this:

```
fastNlMeansDenoising(contourImage,contourImage2);
```

Every time a new frame is loaded, my program should denoise the current frame (contourImage) and write it to contourImage2.

But if I run the code, it returns 0 and exits. What am I doing wrong or is there an alternative way to denoise an image? (It should be fast, because I am processing a video)

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.  It's impossible to diagnose where exactly it's going wrong without seeing what you've actually tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you are using c++ you are not providing the full argument try this that way.

```
cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(contourImage, contourImage2, 10, 10,7, 21);

// This is Original Function to be used.
cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(src[, dst[, h[, templateWindowSize[,     searchWindowSize]]]]) → dst
```

Parameters:
**src** – Input 8-bit 1-channel, 2-channel or 3-channel image.
**dst** – Output image with the same size and type as src .
**templateWindowSize** – Size in pixels of the template patch that is used to compute weights. Should be odd. Recommended value 7 pixels.
**searchWindowSize** – Size in pixels of the window that is used to compute weighted average for given pixel. Should be odd. Affect performance linearly: greater.
**searchWindowsSize** - greater denoising time. Recommended value 21 pixels.
 **h –** Parameter regulating filter strength. Big h value perfectly removes noise but also removes image details, smaller h value preserves details but also preserves some noise