# How can I use fastNlMeansDenoisingColored() in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am new in learning OpenCV. While I was searching for good algorithm to remove noise I found this Function but I have no idea how to use it, so is this function available in OpenCV libraries? If yes, how can I use it.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html) it is available.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104764/opencv-denoising-image-video-frame) is something I found and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915358/fastnlmeansdenoising-does-not-filter-out-noise) is another example.

Comment: @NoahChristopher, when I try to use the function the program didn't recognize it, even through I did include the right libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
void fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, float h=3, float hColor=3, int templateWindowSize=7, int searchWindowSize=21 )
```

This is from the opencv documentation. Therefore try using that function.

A snippet of code I found online may be able to help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat img = imread("a.jpg");
    if (!img.data) {
        cout << "No image found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // first copy the image
    Mat img_gray = img.clone();
    cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    Mat img1;
    cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(img_gray, img1, 3.0, 7, 21);
    imshow("img1", img1);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Adrian I don't really know about Stack's formatting haha.